# What's the story behind the log-normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, intuition

I have been playing around with datasets for the past while for practice. I've noticed that a distribution that looks something like the following appears:

[image]

This shape appears frequently! I can guess it is the log-normal (because I am familiar with the tip-skew of the distribution). I do not understand why this distribution appears in nature so often.

**Is there some intuition to why this comes up frequently?**. My guess is that there is a natural skew in the data. The distribution above was for the prices of lunch bills. The positive skew here would be due to people wanting to pay less for their meals.

Comment: The lognormal can arise through multiplicative processes acting on Gaussian (normal) inputs. Skew here is the name of the problem, not the name of the solution, but many processes have lower bounds at or very near zero but no well defined upper limit

Comment: @Nick For the same reasons Gaussian distributions may appear "in nature" as sums of many small near-independent perturbations, *none of which need be Gaussian*, Lognormal distributions appear as products of many small near-independent perturbations: and again they needn't be Gaussian.

Comment: @whuber Naturally I agree. Indeed, how does the Gaussian arise?

Comment: @whubber If I understand correctly, you're saying that log-normal is due to noise in a Gaussian? If so, I do not agree. SAT scores at Harvard follows a log-normal skewed negatively (people get good grades). This is due to a natural cause of the data itself.

Comment: A lognormal is always right-skewed (except in some parameterisations the normal is a limiting case). What you describe is left-skewed and thus  some other distribution and not lognormal. Indeed I understand SAT to be bounded, so that's inevitable for that reason alone. The existence of other distributions shapes arises for other reasons. I have never heard grading described as a "natural" cause before.

Comment: The natural tendency/cause would be that Harvard students try to get good grades and that causes the skew. My intution is that there is always a story behind skews. But I'd like a concrete answer to the reasons for seeing the log-normal frequently.

Comment: From far being concrete, the best rationale is abstract, some kind of multiplicative spin on the central limit theorem. I don't know a general theory otherwise. You need to separate out reasons for skewness and reasons for lognormality, which your comments seem to conflate. Why not ask, why are many distributions gamma-like or Weibull-like, which their enthusiasts would want to underline? The selection process is that theorists propose distributions as more or less tractable functions with total probability 1 and practical people push those easy to fit and which seem to work some of the time.

Comment: You are right. I just have seen the above shaped distribution very frequently. I was hoping that someone could shed light into why I see it so often.

Comment: The shape you described is not specific of log-normal: a number of other distributions can have the same shape (e.g. gamma).

Comment: Thanks Tim. So for all skewed distributions, do you immediately think of fitting a gamma or log-normal?

Answer (score 5):

As observed in  comments, the lognormal distribution can arise as a kind of multiplicative central limit process. Formalizing, assume $Z_1, Z_2, \dotsc, Z_n$ are iid positive random variables such that the expectation and variance of $\log Z_i$ exists.  We are interested in the (limiting) distribution of $Z=\prod_1^n Z_i$. Write $Y = \log Z = \sum_1^n \log Z_i$. Now we can apply the usual central limit theorem for the sum of $\log Z_i$, obtaining an (limiting) normal distribution for $Y$. It follows that $Z=e^Y$ will have a (limiting) lognormal distribution.

A paper with many good examples is https://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf