# When is the log-normal distribution appropriate?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Iv'e read the Wikipedia entry about the log-normal distribution, as well as a few other sources online, and still do not understand what sort of natural processes are expected to produce a log-normal distribution.

I understand how this distribution arises in processes with many independent factors whose effect is multiplicative, but not which processes are expected to behave in this way.

Both the Wikipedia entry and [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf) review supply several examples of log-normally distributed phenomena, but the only one (aside from the multiplicative Galton board) for which I understand why the effect is multiplicative, is the distribution of bacteria colony sizes - The colonies double in number at each successive division, and the log of the colony size, the number of divisions, should be normally distributed.

**Question:**

Could anyone explain why the many examples of log-normally distributed data are multiplicative in nature, and more generally, how one comes to suspect , a-priori, such multiplicative phenomena as opposed to additive?

Comment: I wouldn't over-emphasise any process or mechanistic rationale.  The lognormal can be a plausible candidate distribution for heterogeneous mixtures regardless of how they were produced. Ditto for positive but right skewed distributions. Also, a distribution doesn't have to fit closely to be worth taking seriously, just more convincing than leading alternatives.

Comment: The leading question across much of statistical sciences is modelling a response in terms of selected predictors. The marginal distribution of the response can be messy if the predictors are; conversely, toy schemes  that show how particular distributions can arise are often highly idealised.

Comment: [NIST Handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3669.htm):"The lognormal distribution is used extensively in reliability applications to model failure times. The lognormal and Weibull distributions are probably the most commonly used distributions in reliability applications." Also google. // Many applications refer to empirical 'fitting' rather then theoretical derivations. // Often used to model numbers of earthquakes at various magnitude; sparse left tail may be due simply  to lack of detection.

Comment: @NickCox: I agree that process considerations shouldn't be over-emphasized. But conversely, they can be under-emphasized. There is always a temptation to just fit lots of distributions and go with the one that fits best. I prefer having at least some kind of argument why a particular distribution makes sense.

Comment: @StephanKolassa We agree. Clearly some rationale beats no rationale, with nothing else said. But for example while the CLT is a fascinating and deep background for thinking about normal distributions. I've found that a normal distribution can fit roughly even when the rationale of additive contributions makes little sense and it can fit poorly even when it makes more sense.

Comment: I am irrationally found of the lognormal. That aside, I have quite often had to point out in practice to colleagues who want to see power law distributions everywhere that their data is better described by a lognormal.

Comment: [A paper answering the question](https://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf) and a similar Q with answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204578/whats-the-story-behind-the-log-normal-distribution

Comment: @NickCox I have very little knowledge of "traditional" statistical theory, but some in machine learning theory, in which this type of curve fitting approach is usually bound to lead to overfitting the data. Is this really how statistical models are fitted? Considering only fit to the data and not an underlying mechanism?

Comment: If there are have good ideas about underlying processes or mechanisms, you would be foolish not to consider them in your thinking. The lognormal has two parameters and its use doesn't to me obviously imply overfitting. Postulating mixtures with several components is an interesting case, as it can be motivated by ideas about the process, but it is dangerous because of the possibility of overfitting unrepeatable quirks in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give one example where one might suspect multiplicative effects, leading to a lognormal distribution.

Retailers like supermarkets have to forecast their demand ([Fildes et al, 2018](http://doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.17747.22565)). Demand is influenced by many factors, like seasonality (intra-weekly and intra-yearly), calendar events, promotions and prices.

A promotion on ice cream will have a much higher additive uplift in summer than in winter. The effect will also be higher on Saturday than on Wednesday (Saturdays are usually much higher selling days than Wednesdays, at least in Europe and the US).

This motivates multiplicative models. Yes, sales are usually count data, so a continuous distribution is not really appropriate, but especially on aggregate data, the approximation is often good enough.

And as a matter of fact, sales forecasting in retail often does use models on logged data. A random example would be autoregressive distributed lags (ADL) models as, e.g., in [Huang, Fildes & Soopramanien (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2014.02.022):

[image: ADL model]

(Sorry for just posting a screenshot, but this is for illustration only, anyway.)

Comment: This kind of thinking has been used for modeling alcohol consumption (I first learned about that under the final exam of my first probability course). Here is a [ncbi paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3352241/) criticizing that empirically, and concluding that Gamma distributions work better.