# Why is the log-normal distribution called "multiplicative? What is multiplicative in it?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

Like in the question. What exactly is "multiplicative" in the log-normal distribution? I heard many times, that additive processes are by nature normal and symmetric, and multiplicative are log-normal. But why?

Comment: Have you looked at [similar posts here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+multiplicative)?  This looks like an answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/295171/919.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3714/919 might also help.